# How to modify input parameters (which then get saved) on new user creation in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, scaffolding

I think this is a simple problem. So far I've ran

`rails generate scaffold User username:string email:string password:string`

to make a new scaffold for the User model. The following is my `user.rb`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :username, presence: true, length: { in: 2..50 }, uniqueness: true
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: true
    validates :password, presence: true, length: { in: 4..50}

    #self.password = 'abcd' #I can't even change the parameter to something hard-coded! 
end
```

I've written a few tests and that works great. My next step is to put the `password` parameter through a hashfunction (which I want to write myself for educational purposes) and save this newly modified string instead of the original string. I don't seem to understand how to do this? Do I create a method in `user.rb` which gets called from the `users_controllers.rb` under the `create` method?

I would like to test this by doing `rails console --sandbox` and writing some tests, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the before_save callback

```
# user.rb model

before_save :hash_password

def hash_password
  self.password = some_hash_function(self.password)
end
```

You have to be careful with this method not to hash the password multiple times. That is you must always hash the clear password and not hash the hashed version. That's why I would do it like this and call the field password_digest and only hash the password if the password attribute is set.

```
# user.rb model

attr_accessor :password
before_save :hash_password

def hash_password
  self.password_digest = some_hash_function(self.password) unless self.password.blank?
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: So would my users table have a column named `password` or `password_digest`? And when I am playing around in the console, should I do `User.new(..., password: "pass")` or `User.new(..., password_hash: "pass")`? Thanks.

Comment: Your table would only have password_digest, but the model would also have password. So when the user fills out the password text field in a form you set the password attribute to that value and then do your hash magic on that value.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but how can I prevent the user from passing a `password_digest`?

Comment: With strong parameters, you just don't include `password_digest` there.